# how to search and retrieve data based on of indexed data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i had indexed the data and elasticsearch allocate it a version.
Now I had updated the indexes by **update API**  a new version will be allocate to it.
Now I want to search data based on  version.
For eg:
my original indexed data is (version=1) :

```
  {
     "name":"Lav"
  }
```

after execution of update query (version=2) :

```
  {
     "name":"Lav",
     "message":"hello elasticsearch"
  }
```

Now I want to perform search operation first in version 1 and then in version 2 .
How it can be done

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you want to make a search based on the values your document had in its version 1.

In fact, the `version` field is just an additional information added to the document. ElasticSearch doesn't keep the values of fields for older versions. Therefore, it's not possible to do a search on the data of an older version.

The `version` field is useful primarily to do some "Optimistic concurrency control" like explained in [this blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/2011/02/08/versioning/).

Comment: yes i want to search based on version. I am looking for retrieval of data of previous version

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible with the `version` field provided by ElasticSearch. You will have to implement it "on your own".